# Remove class from span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `span` tag which consist of multiple  child span  elements. 
I want to remove all the class from the child elements. 
How can I achieve this kindly suggest.
Using Jquery I need to remove sll **"chosen"** class

```
<span class="firstchoose">
<span class="chosen"></span> 
<span class="chosen"></span>
<span class="chosen"></span>
<span class="chosen"></span>
<span class="chosen"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Comment: google/bing/yahoo/... -> "jquery remove class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways

**First**

if you want to remove a specific class using [.removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

```
$(".firstchoose span").removeClass("chosen");
```

**Second**

If you wants to remove all classes [.removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$(".firstchoose span").removeAttr("class");
```

Please find below snippet as well for more info

```js
$(".firstchoose span").removeAttr("class");

//OR

$(".firstchoose span").removeClass("chosen");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="firstchoose">Main Span
<span class="chosen"></span> 
<span class="chosen"></span>
<span class="chosen"></span>
<span class="chosen"></span>
<span class="chosen"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Why answer a down voted question where it's obvious that the OP didn't bother with the most basic of research and that has a dup target and link to the obvious API documentation in the comments?

Comment: sorry its not duplicate,i just look in google,there was multiple span tag, i didnt got it properly, so i added this question and thanks for your time

Comment: @jmoerdyk Ohh that doesn't make any sense to me sir because why this community is running for helping developer community right ? so we are not here to judge OP has researched or not it's a knowledge sharing opportunity so i'm sorry but i'm not agree with you anyways no worries for down voted :) thnku

Comment: Actually it is, `.removeClass()` works the same whether you select a single or multiple elements.

Comment: @Curiousdev I suggest you review the guidelines for asking questions again, because the greater SO community absolutely expects posters to do their own research before asking questions.  It is also up to the community to prevent duplicate questions, hence the existence of the "close as a duplicate" flags/votes.

Comment: @jmoerdyk ohh no no i'm not telling for multiple or single element it's about you have to remove particular class like i have `class1 class2` on tag and wants to delete only `class1` we can use `.removeClass` or remove all classes we can use `.removeAttr` ... related to your second comment i have never read dis so again thank u so much for dis useful info...

Comment: @kittysarvaj your welcome feel free to ask don't be hesitate to ask